# How to add items to janus UIButton c#

Tags: c#, janus

As i see in janus there is UIButton that has an arrow on it , so when you click on it , it can open a menu.

I dont know how to add items so when you click on that Arrow, that is on UIButton, the menu will be open.

Can someone explain me please?

Comment: are you referring to the UIButton with ButtonStyle set to DropDownButton?

Comment: Yes correct ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the ButtonStyle to DropDown. It will now accept a new property called DropDownContextMenu, which will allow you to attach a context menu to the UIButton dropdown.  Here's a quick example setting it in code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        uiButton1.ButtonStyle = Janus.Windows.EditControls.ButtonStyle.DropDown;
        var menu = new Janus.Windows.UI.CommandBars.UIContextMenu();
        menu.Commands.Add(new Janus.Windows.UI.CommandBars.UICommand("1", "Item1"));
        menu.Commands.Add(new Janus.Windows.UI.CommandBars.UICommand("2", "Item2"));
        uiButton1.DropDownContextMenu = menu;
    }
```